# Перестановка строк и столбцов в матрице С#.

Tags: массивы, c#

Здравствуйте, у меня есть задание, которое я не могу решить, не могли бы  мне помочь. Дана квадратная матрица перестановкой строк и столбцов упорядочить элементы диагонали по убыванию в C#.

Вот написал код но он почему не сортирует диагонали...

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
   int buf = 0;
   int[, ] mass = new int[4, 4];
   Random rand = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
           mass[i, j] = rand.Next(10);
   //вывод матрици
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
           Console.Write(mass[i, j]);

       }
       Console.WriteLine(" ");
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       if (i == j)
           if (mass[i, j] > mass[i + 1, j + 1]) {

               // перестановка строк
               for (int s = 0; s < 1; s++)

                   for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                       buf = mass[s, k];
                       mass[s, k] = mass[s + 1, k];
                       mass[s + 1, k] = buf;

                   }
                   // перестановка столбцов
               for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++)

                   for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
                   buf = mass[s, k];
                   mass[s, k] = mass[s, k + 1];
                   mass[s, k + 1] = buf;
               }
           }

           Console.WriteLine(" ");
           //вывод
           for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                   Console.Write(mass[i, j]);

               }
               Console.WriteLine(" ");
           }

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: @Alex031, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Не могу придумать сам алгоритм.

Comment: @Alex031 как верно было сказано выше, здесь не выполняют заданий, не пишут лабораторных и не придумывают алгоритмы за студентов. Здесь будут рады вам помочь при условии, что вы уже что-то сделали сами, а не ждете, чтобы кто-то за вас сделал вашу работу.

Comment: Обновил кодю

Comment: так вам Си или C# нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите. Ваша задача естественно распадается на следующие подзадачи:

1. Поменять местами `i`-ую и `j`-ую строки матрицы.
2. Отсортировать строки по ключу, равному соответствующему диагональному элементу.

В качестве сортировки для учебного задания вполне подойдёт пузырёк.

Дальше пробуйте сами.

[Да, решение неоптимально, можно было бы сначала определить нужную перестановку, работая с диагональю, и лишь затем переставлять строки.]

**Обновление**

Ну, перестановка строк — дорогая операция по сравнению с перестановкой их индексов. Поэтому дешевле было бы сначала отсортировать индексы, а потом определить по отсортированным индексам перестановку строк, разложить её в произведение циклов и попереставлять строки — таким образом, каждый элемент переставляется по разу (плюс один раз на цикл).

Comment: извините можно по подробней на счет того что решение не оптимально

Comment: Ну, перестановка строк — дорогая операция по сравнению с перестановкой их индексов. Поэтому дешевле было бы сначала отсортировать индексы, а потом определить по отсортированным индексам перестановку строк, разложить её в произведение циклов и попереставлять строки — таким образом, каждый элемент переставляется по разу (плюс один раз на цикл).